# Wrap two divs with td with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sugarcrm

I have the following code in HTML and it's inside a table and in one `<td>`. The fields are in sugarCRM CE. The first `<div>` is original from the system(studio). The second one with a span inside is created with jQuery.

My task is to wrap() them with jQuery into two separated td's.

```
<div style="width: 100%; min-height: 10px; display: inline;" ondblclick="EDV.show_edit('google_keyword_1_c','varchar')" class="div_value" id="google_keyword_1_c_detailblock" target_id="google_keyword_1_c">
                <span style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% whitesmoke;" class="sugar_field" id="google_keyword_1_c_span">qweqweqw</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="display:inline" id="spany_span"><a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=qweqweqw Varna VN" target="_blank">Google</a>
            </span>
```

They are five fields and i am setting the jQuery for each with this piece of code:

```
$('div#google_keyword_'+i+'_c_detailblock').wrap('<table><tbody><tr><td>').css('display','table').after('<div style="display: table"><span style="display: inline" id="spany"><a href="' + url + '" target="_blank">Google</a></span></div>');
```

My problem is when I try to `$('#google_keyword_1_c_detailblock').wrap('<td>');` it's putting the `<div>` where it should but the end `</div>` is set before closing the `<tbody>` and the `</tr>`.

This is the desire HTML I want to achieve with the help of jQuery.

```
<table>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div style="width: 100%; min-height: 10px; display: inline;" ondblclick="EDV.show_edit('google_keyword_1_c','varchar')" class="div_value" id="google_keyword_1_c_detailblock" target_id="google_keyword_1_c">
                <span style="background: none repeat scroll 0% 0% whitesmoke;" class="sugar_field" id="google_keyword_1_c_span">qweqweqw</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <span style="display:inline" id="spany_span"><a href="http://www.google.com/search?q=qweqweqw Varna VN" target="_blank">Google</a>
            </span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```